# App crashes while loading large size file(xls) in WebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, swipe

I am facing an issue while loading **xls** files(above **1mb**) in swift4. When I load the file for the first time, it works perfectly, but when I go back and load the page again, the app **crashes**.
I get an error like :

> WebThread (15): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18c1c3f00)

Code shown below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCVC
   let encodedStr = escapedString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
   let url = URL(string: encodedStr!)
   let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
   cell.webView.loadRequest(requestObj)  
   return cell
  }
```

I have used **collectionView** since it contains both **imageView** and **webView**(uses swipe control), loads **image**/**webView** by getting the path.

[image: When the app crashes, it gets redirected to this page]

[image: This is my console page]

[image: Console page]

Comment: Can you please post the whole console log? You unforce wrap way too many properties, I have a hunch the problem is there.

Comment: No crash reports in console, I just get the error message : WebThread (15): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18c1c3f00)

Comment: Hmm, can you post a screenshot of your console log? I'd like to see the logs of the app when it starts until the last log before it crashes.

Comment: I have posted the console image.

Comment: I can see there is more data printed in the log because half a date is still seen in the bottom of the picture you posted. Please post **all** of your console log.

Comment: I have posted two links(console pages)

Comment: I see stuff getting printed in your console but no `print` statements in your code. Please post all your code.

Comment: First narrow down to functionalities one-by-one to find the problematic part. You should first try with large excel file then with small excel file and load it multiple times. If using small excel file there is no crash then problem is in loading large files on the other side if small files also produces same result then problem is in the code, share relevant code at this point.